# svnadmin dump returns error insufficient disk space

Tags: amazon-ec2, svn, amazon-s3

I have a SVN repo that is around 35GB after dumping.  I know this is huge, but our business requires that all revisions of all files and libraries be tracked.

I have Apache Subversion hosted on an AWS EC2 instance, with / partition of 8GB.  I mounted an S3 volume as /mnt/svn and another as /mnt/backup.

The problem arises when I run a backup using svnadmin dump.

```
sudo svnadmin dump /mnt/svn/repos/repo1 > /mnt/backup/repo1_$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").dump
```

I will see that the freespace of / partition decreasing when the backup runs, and when it has reached 8GB (the size of the partition), the backup then returns error "insufficient disk space".

My question is, why is it using / for the backup process?  Is there some temp area that it is using?

Comment: If are using s3fs, it appears to "copy the source file to a local file temporarily when s3fs uploads the file". If you have ephemeral storage on your instance, you can point the temporary path to the ephemeral volume using the use_cache option. See [Issue #416](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=416#hc1)

Comment: Thanks @cyberx86!  I will try mounting an ephemeral storage and remount s3fs with the use_cache option.